# convex hull of roots of a polynomial.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

This question deals with some consequences of the Gauss-Lucas theorem. Suppose that $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a polynomial. If I know that $f^{\prime}$ has precisely two positive real roots, for instance, what exactly can I deduce from the Gauss-Lucas theorem about the roots of $f$? The only conclusion I can draw is that the convex hull of the roots of $f$ must enclose a portion of the positive real axis. My wish is to be able to say something about the roots of $f$ - how many exist, and whether they are (real) positive as well. It would also be nice to be able to completely describe the convex hull of the roots of $f$.

Comment: If you use Gauss-Lucas as a black box I think I agree that your conclusion is all you can get out of it. The black box approach to Gauss-Lucas does not fully leverage the "precisely two real roots" aspect of the problem. Is anything else known about $f$?

Comment: Are you allowing that while two of the roots of $f'$ are real, it may have any number of complex roots that are not real?  Or did you mean that up to a scalar multiple, $f'$ is a real quadratic polynomial with two distinct roots?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to completely describe the convex hull of the roots since one of the vertex must be a root (probably) and we rarely get to know the roots of a polynomial. An interesting cuestion would be if we could measure the area of the convex hull, or if we can get a reletion between the angles of the vertexs

Comment: @Leslie Townes: In this example, I know that $f$ is a cubic polynomial, and that (under some constraints I have imposed) $f^{\prime}$ has exactly two real roots.

Comment: Can't you just calculate the roots?

Comment: I don't want to calculate the roots.

Comment: If $f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^nA_jz^j$ with $n>0$ and $A_n\ne 0$ then let $M=|A_n|^{-1}\max \{|A_j|: j<n\}.$ Then $|z|\ge 1+M\implies$ $ |f(z)|\ge |A_n|(1+M)^n-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}M|A_n|(1+M)^j> 0.$ In some cases, applying this after a change of variable, e.g. $z=Kz',$ may give a much sharper bound for the zeroes of $f$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Can you please explain the hypothesis $|z|\geq 1+M$ in your contribution. It looks like you are considering $z\in\mathbb{C}$ outside of a circle of radius $1+M$. What is the motivation, and what is the goal?

Comment: I think he's showing you bounds for the Roots of the Polynomial

Comment: I don't know if this helps. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marden%27s_theorem